# How to add enctype to multipart/form-data to comment form?

Tags: comments, comment-form

I need a way to change the encoding type for my comment form, without hacking the core files.

I'm aware of the function to work on the post editing form: `post_edit_form_tag`.

I've tried this:

```
jQuery('#comment_form').attr("enctype","multipart/form-data");
```

But it doesn't work, the only next step I know of is to hack the source code...
Any help would be very much appreciated—thanks in advance!

Comment: _How_ is this not working? Any errors, warnings, strange behavior? The ID is correct? And it **is** an ID (and not a class)?

Comment: @t f, It's just not doing anything, I'm using an id and it is correct...

Comment: Posting **answers** as **comments** just results in cluttered comment threads...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One Trick Pony answered the question, here's his solution:

```
jQuery('#comment_form')[0].encoding = 'multipart/form-data';
```

And [here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8b96/) of it.

Answer (score -1):

The ID in the form tag can vary in some themes. Instead, you can handle the process by adding a custom ID.

```
function custom_comment_form_id($comment_form)
{
        $existing_control = isset($comment_form['class_form']) ? $comment_form['class_form'] : ""; 
        $comment_form['class_form'] = trim($existing_control . ' vono_image_attr_id');
    return $comment_form;
}
add_filter('comment_form_defaults', 'custom_comment_form_id');
```

Afterwards, add the generated custom ID to the jQuery code.